ITaskbarList interface not setting proper state when using "SetProgressValue"
I have the following class in a console application
public static class TaskbarSetter
{
    static IntPtr windowHandle;

    public enum TaskbarStates
    {
        NoProgress = 0,
        Indeterminate = 0x1,
        Normal = 0x2,
        Error = 0x4,
        Paused = 0x8
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("ea1afb91-9e28-4b86-90e9-9e9f8a5eefaf")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface ITaskbarList3
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        void ActivateTab(IntPtr hwnd);

        [PreserveSig]
        void AddTab(IntPtr hwnd);

        [PreserveSig]
        void DeleteTab(IntPtr hwnd);

        [PreserveSig]
        void HrInit();

        [PreserveSig]
        void MarkFullscreenWindow(IntPtr hwnd, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fFullscreen);

        [PreserveSig]
        void SetActiveAlt(IntPtr hwnd);

        [PreserveSig]
        void SetProgressState(IntPtr hwnd, TaskbarStates state);

        [PreserveSig]
        void SetProgressValue(IntPtr hwnd, ulong ullCompleted, ulong ullTotal);
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    private class TaskbarInstance { }

    private static readonly ITaskbarList3 taskbarInstance = (ITaskbarList3)new TaskbarInstance();
    private static readonly bool taskbarSupported = Environment.OSVersion.Version >= new Version(6, 1);

    static TaskbarSetter()
        => windowHandle = Interop.GetConsoleWindow();

    public static void SetState(TaskbarStates taskbarState)
    {
        if (taskbarSupported)
            taskbarInstance.SetProgressState(windowHandle, taskbarState);
    }

    public static void SetValue(double progressValue, double progressMax)
    {
        if (taskbarSupported)
            taskbarInstance.SetProgressValue(windowHandle, (ulong)progressValue, (ulong)progressMax);
    }
}

This is the code for Interop.GetConsoleWindow():
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

I put it together from information on the internet about the ITaskbarList interfaces. The aim of this class is to facilitate the setting of the different taskbar states (solid green, flashing green, etc.) and to my mind, it should work fine.
However when I execute the following code:
    TaskbarSetter.SetState(TaskbarProgress.TaskbarStates.Normal);
    TaskbarSetter.SetValue(5, 10);

the taskbar state of the console window turns to "Error", i.e. solid red color and I cannot understand why, as the taskbar state "normal" should be a solid green color.
I don't understand what is not working properly in this code.
